# Is this following sequence construction legitimate?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have $\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$. Now I want to find a disjoint infinite union of sets that is equal to it.

Let $C_1=E_1$, $C_2=E_2-E_1$, $C_3=E_3-E_2-E_1$ $\cdots$. Then clearly $\cup_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ is an infinite union of disjoint sets.

Is this construction legitimate? Is there any set theoretic axioms allowing it or prohibiting it?

If not, how about $C_n=E_n\cap(\cap_{i=1}^{n-1} C_i')$. They are exactly the same sets, but written in different ways. It seemed to me the first way is more natural while the second is more legitimate somehow.

Comment: You could also let $C_1=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ and $C_n=\emptyset$ for $n>1$, couldn't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that could prevent legitimacy is the use of "$\ldots$" in your construction.
However, to clarify your construction, you might define $D_n=\bigcup\{\,E_k\mid k<n\,\}$ and then $C_n=D_{n+1}-D_n$.
(In fact, I'd rather say that your alternative method using complements is slightly more suspicious, axiomatization-wise)

Note that we used the well-ordering of the naturals, so you might have more difficulties with $\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb R}E_x$, say.